# NEHotspotHelper: Not Able to Send Web Request in Authenticating State of Authentication State Machine

Tags: ios, authentication, captivenetwork, captiveportal, nehotspothelper

I have implemented the `NEHotspotHelper` so that I can perform authentication in the background for networks with a captive portal.

I need to perform a web request in the 'authenticating' state so that I can retrieve the Wispr and also access an API.

However, when I try to use `URLSession` to send a web request, the request fails. This is the error:

```
[594:88737] dnssd_clientstub read_all(7) DEFUNCT
[594:88783] TIC TCP Conn Failed [4:0x1c0177a00]: 12:8 Err(-65554)
[594:88783] Task <FFD0DAE6-4864-437D-94F2-C9ED5D5748E2>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
[594:88783] Task <FFD0DAE6-4864-437D-94F2-C9ED5D5748E2>.<1> finished with error - code: -1003
```

See a snippet of my code:

---

```
 let registered = NEHotspotHelper.register(options: options, queue: queue) { (cmd: NEHotspotHelperCommand) in
    print("Received command: \(cmd.commandType.rawValue)")
    if cmd.commandType == NEHotspotHelperCommandType.filterScanList {
        //Get all available hotspots
        print("filter scan list")
        var list: [NEHotspotNetwork] = cmd.networkList!
        var response: NEHotspotHelperResponse
        for l in list {
            if (l.ssid=="my-ssid") {
                response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.success)
            } else {
                response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.failure)                       
            }
            response.setNetworkList([chosenNetwork])
            response.deliver()
        }   
    } else if cmd.commandType == NEHotspotHelperCommandType.evaluate {
        if let network = cmd.network {            
            if (network.ssid=="my-ssid") {            
                network.setConfidence(NEHotspotHelperConfidence.high)
                let response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.success)
                response.setNetwork(network)                 
                response.deliver() //Respond back
            } else {
                let response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.failure)
                response.deliver()
            }
        }
    } else if cmd.commandType == NEHotspotHelperCommandType.authenticate {
        print("authenticate")
        var response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.unsupportedNetwork)
        if let network = cmd.network{
            if network.ssid == "my-ssid"{
                self.queryUrl()
                response = cmd.createResponse(NEHotspotHelperResult.success)
            }
        }
        response.deliver() //Respond back                    
    }
}

func queryUrl(){
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    config.allowsCellularAccess = false;

    let session = URLSession.init(configuration: config)

    let url = URL(string: "https://172.217.20.35")

    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: url!){(data, response, error) in
        if  data==nil {
            print(data as Any)            
        }
        else{
            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as Any)
        }
        semaphore.signal()
    }

    task.resume()
    _ = semaphore.wait(timeout: .distantFuture)    
}
```

Comment: You should always deliver. But only once per command received.

Comment: Change your web request to a synchronous call, and only deliver once after you have finished logging in via the request. If your request times out, still deliver success. Don't make the OS wait too long for you to return something either. I'd say, 1 minute max

Comment: Thank you @Pierre, I have used an a synchronous call by using semaphores but it still does not work. (See queryUrl method) I should add that I am very new to Swift and iOS Development.
 This is the error: 
[284:19580] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c416b340]: 1:50 Err(50)
[284:19580] Task <30A63185-9A5A-4F94-ACE7-EC63504C8B05>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50])
[284:19580] Task <30A63185-9A5A-4F94-ACE7-EC63504C8B05>.<1> finished with error - code: -1009

Comment: If you try and implement what i've said, you will get it to work. Try your auth request, but if it fails with the above, return success result. iOS will finish the connection to the SSID and see that it needs some sort of authentication, the Authenticate|Maintain command will be posted again, the second time around the web request should work fine. Implement a switch just like my answer below

Comment: Hey Pierre, once iOS is in the Authenticated state, a Maintaining timer is scheduled to run 300 secs after. I think that's too long to wait for a successful authentication. I wish there was a command for the state 'Authenticated'. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/Hotspot_Network_Subsystem_Guide/Contents/AuthStateMachine.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016639-CH2-SW1

Comment: Hey @Pierre, did you use a URLSession datatask for the web request or did you use NWTCPConnection?

Comment: I actually use `Xamarin`, but try `NSMutableURLRequest`. See this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests/WorkingWithHTTPAndHTTPSRequests.html

Comment: Thanks @Pierre, I'll try it. So in your code, did you only get the web request to work in the 'Maintain' state and/or also in the 'Authenticating' state?

Comment: In Authenticate state

Comment: ok @Pierre, MutableURLRequest is deprecated it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also facing the similar issue. However, I found that developer need to bind the request with the received command before making web request to the connected network. All you need to do is to make `NSMutableURLRequest` and then call `hitTestURLRequest.bind(to: command)` because bind function is defined in the category of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the just of it:

```
if cmd.commandType
    filterScanList
        - SetConfidence to each of your networks in cmd.networkList - High and add to a local list variable.
        - create Response.Success
        - set Response.NetworkList to your list of confident networks
        ----
        - deliver Response
    Evaluate or PresentUI
        //If it's your network
        - SetConfidence to cmd.network - High
        - create Response.Success
        - set Response.Network to cmd.network
        //If it's not your network
        - create Response.UnsupportedNetwork
        ----
        - deliver Response
    Authenticate or Maintain
        //If it's your network
        - SetConfidence to cmd.network - High
        - create Response.Success
        - set Response.Network to cmd.network
        - TRY AUTHENTICATE HERE SYNCHRONOUSLY
        //If it's not your network
        - create Response.UnsupportedNetwork
        ----
        - deliver Response
    Logoff or None
        - create Response.Success
        ----
        - deliver Response
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have reported problem with name server resolution from `NEHotspotHelper` callback. Try using an IP address to make the call.

Also don't forget `URLSession` works asynchronously. You will need to call `response.deliver()` only after the web service calls finishes.

Comment: Hey @RajV, Thank you. I have tried an IP address and used semaphores to create a synchronous call. It still does not work. I am also new to Swift. I still get the following error: 
[284:19580] TIC TCP Conn Failed [1:0x1c416b340]: 1:50 Err(50) [284:19580] Task <30A63185-9A5A-4F94-ACE7-EC63504C8B05>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -1009 [1:50]) 
[284:19580] Task <30A63185-9A5A-4F94-ACE7-EC63504C8B05>.<1> finished with error - code: -1009