# Connect to the Wi-Fi network from within the app without internet access

Tags: ios11, networkextension, nehotspothelper

I am developing hotspot helper application which tries to connect to the captive network after connecting to it, I need to handle the authentication within the app.

## Approach 1

I used NEHotspotConfigurationManager in order to programmatically connect to the WiFi network and it works great. The problem i am facing is after connecting to the captive network iOS does not send the request to the connected network until the connected network has internet access or I manually go to the settings and it pops up the web page for authentication and i click cancel and select use without internet.

## Approach 2

Second approach i used is by using NEHotSpotHelper as described in [this tutorial](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2016/11/02/working-with-nehotspothelper/)

In this approach when I receive the commandType authenticate it does not send request to the Wi-Fi network (If the device is connected to the 4g the request goes over it otherwise it returns internet connection appears to be offline)

So how can i authenticate the user from the app after connecting to the WiFi with limited access?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that developer need to bind the request with the received command before making web request to the connected network. All you need to do is to make `NSMutableURLRequest` and then call `hitTestURLRequest.bind(to: command)` because bind function is defined in the category of `NSMutableURLRequest`.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50753526/1796092